should I delete 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes' after migrate to .net8?
I am working on migrate from .net6 to .net8.I had read the documentation says do not use anymore package references related to Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.*. In currently project the openAPI is using decoration like [OpenApiOperation] but this is rely on Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes. If I remove the code will break. How am I supports to do for this?

Can you share your .csproj file and share the code which you have tried?

Steps to migrate and use OpenAPI in .NET 8:
Remove obsolete packages:
Remove all references to the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.* packages from the project.
Use Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker:
In .NET 8, the recommended approach is to use Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker instead of Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs. Update your project to use this package.


should I delete 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes' after migrate to .net8?


Remove the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs packages from your project file.
Check the .csproj file for the packages like below:

.csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.7.0" OutputItemType="Analyzer" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="7.0.0" />
    <!-- Add other package references as needed -->
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>



The package Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi has been installed.
Below is the sample code of after migration to .net 8.0. check the attributes and packages.

Code:
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;

public static class MyFunction
{
    [Function(nameof(MyFunction.Run))]
    [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "Run", tags: new[] { "example" })]
    public static HttpResponseData Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext executionContext)
    {
        var response = req.CreateResponse();
        response.WriteString("Hello, world!");
        return response;
    }
}


For further clarification about packages after migration check my SO Answer

Hi, seems I cannot found 'using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;
' I installed all the necessary packages I could but with no luck. I can only found 'using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;
' and it works for me

Glad it resolved.
